# Window on load doesn't change content

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

I have a Backbone view in which I want to fire a event `resizeMovieFrame` when the view gets initialized. It reacts to the `$(window).on("load", @resizeMovieFrame)` because 'hello' gets shown in the console.

But the resize code doesn't do anything on load. But when I resize my browser it does work. So I'm thinking that when the `$(window).on("resize", @resizeMovieFrame)` gets fired there aren't any `.movie-frame` divs to resize. If this is the case, what would be the propper load order?

```
class Movieseat.Views.MovieseatsIndex extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['movieseats/index']
  id: 'something'

  initialize: ->
    @listenTo @collection, 'change', @renderEntries, this
    @listenTo @collection, 'add', @renderEntries, this
    @listenTo @collection, 'destroy', @renderEntries, this
    $(window).on("resize", @resizeMovieFrame)
    $(window).on("load", @resizeMovieFrame)

  render: -> 
    $(@el).html(@template(entries: @collection))
    this

  events: -> 
    "click li": "addEntry" 
    "click .remove": "destroyEntry" 

  addEntry: (e) -> 
    movie_title = $(e.target).parent().find('.movie-title').text()
    poster_path = $(e.target).parent().find('img').attr('src')
    release_date = $(e.target).parent().find('.release_date').text()
    console.log poster_path
    @collection.create title: movie_title, image: poster_path, release_date: release_date

  destroyEntry: (e) -> 
    thisid = @$(e.currentTarget).closest('div').parent().data('id')
    @collection.get(thisid).destroy()

  renderEntries: (entry) ->
    view = new Movieseat.Views.Showmovie(collection: @collection)
    $('#movie-container').html(view.render().el)

  resizeMovieFrame: ->
    equalheight = (container) ->
      currentTallest = 0
      currentRowStart = 0
      rowDivs = new Array()
      $el = undefined
      topPosition = 0
      $(container).each ->
        $el = $(this)
        $($el).height "auto"
        topPostion = $el.position().top
        unless currentRowStart is topPostion
          currentDiv = 0
          while currentDiv < rowDivs.length
            rowDivs[currentDiv].height currentTallest
            currentDiv++
          rowDivs.length = 0 # empty the array
          currentRowStart = topPostion
          currentTallest = $el.height()
          rowDivs.push $el
        else
          rowDivs.push $el
          currentTallest = (if (currentTallest < $el.height()) then ($el.height()) else (currentTallest))
        currentDiv = 0
        while currentDiv < rowDivs.length
          rowDivs[currentDiv].height currentTallest
          currentDiv++
        return

      return

    $(window).load ->
      equalheight ".movie-frame"
      return

    $(window).resize ->
      equalheight ".movie-frame"
      return

    console.log ('hello')
```

The `resizeMovieFrame` event resizes all the `.movie-frame` divs to the same height.

Answer (score 0):

you probably need to bind the context of the `resizeWindowFrame` function.

```
resizeMovieFrame: =>
```